# How is transparency achieved in cocoa applications

Tags: macos, cocoa, opencv

I am trying to understand how is transparency actually implemented in cocoa applications. I was expecting the standard blending equation to be used i.e.
BlendedColour = alpha * layerColour + (1-alpha)*backgroundColour

However, I noticed that there is the slight difference in the blended colour expected if the above equation is used. To verify it, I did a small experiment as follows:

1.) Created a window, added a transparency of 0.8 to the window and grabbed a screenshot.

2.) I took a screenshot of the part of the screen where I am overlaying the window in step one without the window and overlayed the same image as in step 1, using the equation mentioned above. (I used openCV for that).

There is a slight difference in the colours for the two images, if you look closely. I wanted to understand what is causing the difference.

Resources:

1.) Images from Step 1 and Step2 respectively

[image: Step 1 image]
[image: Step 2 Image]

2.) Code used in step 1

```
NSRect windowRect = {0,0,200,200};

m_NSWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

[m_NSWindow setTitle:@"overlayWindow"];

[m_NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

g_imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,200,200)];

[m_NSWindow.contentView addSubview:g_imageView];



[m_NSWindow setOpaque:NO];

[m_NSWindow setAlphaValue:0.8];



NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil

                                                                     pixelsWide:200

                                                                     pixelsHigh:200

                                                                  bitsPerSample:8

                                                                samplesPerPixel:4

                                                                       hasAlpha:YES

                                                                       isPlanar:NO

                                                                 colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace

                                                                bitmapFormat:NSAlphaNonpremultipliedBitmapFormat

                                                                    bytesPerRow:(200*4)

                                                                   bitsPerPixel:32];



memcpy(imageRep.bitmapData,m_paintBuffer.data,160000);

NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(200,200);

NSImage* myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: imageSize];

[myImage addRepresentation:imageRep];

[g_imageView setImage:myImage];
```

4.) Code for step 2

```
void overlayImage(const cv::Mat &background, const cv::Mat &foreground,
cv::Mat &output, cv::Point2i location)
{


background.copyTo(output);


// start at the row indicated by location, or at row 0 if location.y is negative.
for (int y = max(location.y, 0); y < background.rows; ++y)
{
    int fY = y - location.y; // because of the translation

    // we are done of we have processed all rows of the foreground image.
    if (fY >= foreground.rows)
        break;

    // start at the column indicated by location, 

    // or at column 0 if location.x is negative.
    for (int x = max(location.x, 0); x < background.cols; ++x)
    {
        int fX = x - location.x; // because of the translation.

        // we are done with this row if the column is outside of the foreground image.
        if (fX >= foreground.cols)
            break;

        // determine the opacity of the foregrond pixel, using its fourth (alpha) channel.
        double opacity =
            ((double)foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + 3])

            / 255.;


        // and now combine the background and foreground pixel, using the opacity, 

        // but only if opacity > 0.
        for (int c = 0; opacity > 0 && c < output.channels(); ++c)
        {
            unsigned char foregroundPx =
                foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + c];
            unsigned char backgroundPx =
                background.data[y * background.step + x * background.channels() + c];
            output.data[y*output.step + output.channels()*x + c] =
                backgroundPx * (1. - opacity) + foregroundPx * opacity;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The `opacity` value in code for step 2, calculates to `(204/255.)` for all the pixels